# Mod_wsgi/Django not responding to requests, Apache is serving static files just fine

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

Static files are getting served *(example, http://iamshobhit.com/media/css/home.css)*

But urls which mod_wsgi/django are supposed to take care of, just **wait forever for response** *(example, http://iamshobhit.com)*

**Apache error log** (LogLevel debug) shows:-

```
[Fri Dec 06 04:23:27.256038 2013] [:info] [pid 4980:tid 140580561024832] mod_wsgi (pid=4980): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.339088 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 175.100.182.59:56886] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.339370 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 175.100.182.59:56886] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.339661 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 175.100.182.59:56886] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.339732 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 175.100.182.59:56886] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.359602 2013] [:info] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] mod_wsgi (pid=4980): Create interpreter 'iamshobhit.com|'.
[Fri Dec 06 04:24:19.361155 2013] [:info] [pid 4980:tid 140580260644608] [client 175.100.182.59:56886] mod_wsgi (pid=4980, process='', application='iamshobhit.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app/wsgi.py'.
```

and then stops producing any further output.
The browser waits forever for response and finally says *"No data received"*

Any Ideas as to what I might be missing?

I have been struggling with this for two days now, and I am still where I started...

**Here's the server config -**

```
AWS free micro-instance, Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-57-virtual x86_64)
Apache/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.3 Django/1.6.0
```

Here are some config files I think might be important

**httpd.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**VirtualHost config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName iamshobhit.com
  ServerAlias www.iamshobhit.com
  ServerAdmin shobhit.v87@gmail.com

  Alias /robots.txt /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/favicon.ico
  Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/

  <Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media>
  Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app/wsgi.py
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

ppath = '/home/ubuntu/www/mkapp'

sys.path.append(ppath)
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHONPATH", ppath)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "marketing_app.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you end up fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have installed the module libapache2-mod-wsgi
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

if that a case you don't have to use the file wsgi.py like a python file but it 
should be a .wsgi file i mean you should create a file with the extension file.wsgi
if you want to load it with your apache server

so wsgi.py  ====> filename.wsgi

```
import os, sys
wsgi_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
project_dir = os.path.dirname(wsgi_dir)
sys.path.append(project_dir)
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/www/mkapp')
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/.python-egg'
project_settings = os.path.join(project_dir,'settings')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='marketing_app.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application =django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

1 - if your apache is installed from source (i mean download and install with command)
    add the line LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so in the virtualhost config
    you don't have to grant something else.

Virtualhost Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Listen 81
  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so 
  ServerName iamshobhit.com
  ServerAlias www.iamshobhit.com
  ServerAdmin shobhit.v87@gmail.com

  Alias /robots.txt /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/favicon.ico
  Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app/filename.wsgi
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2- if the apache server is installed from package (apache2)
  you have only to enable the mod_wsgi module

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName iamshobhit.com
  ServerAlias www.iamshobhit.com
  ServerAdmin shobhit.v87@gmail.com

  WSGIScriptReloading On
  WSGIProcessGroup servername
  WSGIDaemonProcess servername user=username processes=10 threads=1 maximum-requests=500

  Alias /robots.txt /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/favicon.ico
  Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/files/media/

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app/filename.wsgi
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have that stuff in httpd.conf. Move:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

into the VirtualHost definition.

Read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

as to why WSGIApplicationGroup of %{GLOBAL} may be required. For you that is not being picked up with the configuration you had and so you are likely using a third party Python package with a C extension which doesn't work with sub interpreters and so it is deadlocking.

Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

and consider why you are still using embedded mode.

Also go try with a WSGI hello world program rather than your Django application. This most likely will confirm there is nothing wrong with Apache/mod_wsgi but that issues are caused by your application and the modules it is loading.

Comment: How can I make a WSGI hello world application? Do I just stick some code into `wsgi.py` i.e. some file writing?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the following to the wsgi file:

```
ppath2 = '/home/ubuntu/www/mkapp/marketing_app'
sys.path.append(ppath2)
```